# Activating menu in Xfce panel via command-line

Tags: xubuntu

What is the command for activating the app menu in the Xfce panel? It would be the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> on Windows. I know that there is a command for LXPanel, is there a way to do the same in Xfce panel?

Comment: I wish the command, to then, assign a keyboard shortcut to, using ccsm (compiz config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu
```

Comment: In my system  Ctrl+Esc  opens the Whisker Menu...